# Chart.js cannot read property '0' of undefined - bar charts

Tags: angular

I am using chart.js for printing bar charts and pie charts. This is my code:

```
this.barChartData = [];
 this.barChartLabels = [];
  this.analytics.forEach(data => {
     debugger;
      var splittedlabel = data.label.substring(0, 7)+ '..';
      this.barChartData.push(data.total);
      this.barChartLabels.push(splittedlabel);
  })
 alert(this.barChartData+ " " +this.barChartLabels);
```

I am getting correct output in alert but the following error in console:
[image]

Also the output chart is broken for this.

[image]

Please help as the same file works fine with static data.

Comment: Can you show us `this.analytics`?

Comment: for the broken output chart, try arranging your data in ascending or descending order. one should hopefully work

Comment: @Christoph yes sure.         [{"total":"1","label":"Agile has no planning"}]

Comment: Here is array for above bar chart:                                                                               2,1,1,1 Working..,Followi..,Process..,Contrac..